# Errors ITMS-90530 and ITMS-90502 when I upload my app to the store

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7

I have a strange error when I try to upload my app to the AppStore. I have two errors: **ITMS-905030** and **ITMS-90502**. These errors says that my app is only configured to support 64-bit. But it's not!
Here are the errors:

[image: Errors I get when I upload my app to the AppStore]

And here is my configuration for my Target and Project :

[image]

My project also have some library added via Pods, but I don't think that the cause of the problem. The deployment target is set to **7.0**. I archive this project with an iPhone 6 (iOS 9.0.2) connected.
Could somebody help me with that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems that you are using **Debug** configuration when archiving, and the **Debug** configuration has **Build Active Architecture Only** enabled.

Answer (score 6):

Try  this  way ：

Pull your iPhone out of the USB interface

then  try to upload the AppStore Again.

---

I hope  i could  help you

Answer (score 2):

check **Build Active Architecture Only** in `Build Settings > Architectures`

If **YES**, xcode will determine the architecture of the device connected (ACTIVE) and it will build for that only.

If **NO**, xcode will build for all architectures considering your minimumOSVersion

So unplugging your `64 bit phone` or selecting `Generic iOS Device` will fix the issue

NOTE: setting `Build Active Architecture`to `YES` is faster when building, so use it when you need it

Answer (score 0):

I try this in edit schema **Archive**  debug to set release and also **Run** also set Release . I hope this is help for you. Thanks 
 
 
[image]